# Is there a left join in coldfusion query of queries?

Tags: sql-server, coldfusion

Since I'm new to using coldfusion according to my co-worker we can't do left join in a coldfusion query of queries. So this is what we would do a little "trick" to do a left join.
example:

```
<cfquery datasource="Intranet" name="GroupStarsGiven">
    SELECT execoffice_status, submitterdept, COUNT(*) as 'totalstarsgiven'
    FROM CSEReduxResponses
    WHERE execoffice_status = 1
    GROUP BY execoffice_status, submitterdept
</cfquery>

<cfquery dbtype="query" name="GetTotalStarsGiven">
    SELECT *
    FROM GroupStarsGiven, GetDepartments
    WHERE GroupStarsGiven.submitterdept = GetDepartments.csedept_id
</cfquery>

<cfquery name="joinQuery2" dbtype="query" >
SELECT *
FROM GetTotalStarsGiven
WHERE GetTotalStarsGiven.csedept_id = -1
</cfquery>

<cfset QueryAddRow(joinQuery2)>

<cfquery name="GetUnion2" dbtype="query" >
SELECT *
FROM GetUnion, GetTotalStarsGiven
WHERE GetUnion.csedept_id = GetTotalStarsGiven.csedept_id

UNION

SELECT GetUnion.*, joinQuery2.*
FROM GetUnion, joinQuery2
WHERE GetUnion.csedept_id NOT IN (#ValueList(GetTotalStarsGiven.csedept_id)#)
ORDER BY csedept_name ASC
</cfquery
```

Is this the way to do left join in coldfusion? Just want to make sure since I not able to find a good article on this.
thanks

Comment: You might want to go vote for https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3687749. This shortfall was first reported in 2007 (https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3031961) and Adobe haven't bothered to do anything about it yet :-(

Comment: Where does `GetUnion` com from?

Comment: That's I do left joins with Q of Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you are trying to do here, but the answer to "there's no left join in ColdFusion?" is: it depends. You can certainly use a left join in a query to an external database, provided the database supports it (I can't think of a relational database that doesn't). But you can't do joins in a ColdFusion query-of-query; you have to resort to creative use of unions to accomplish that.

However, the need for a join in a query-of-query can usually be eliminated by effective use of joins in the initial query to the database.  Exceptions to that would be if you needed to join queries from completely different ColdFusion data sources, or to the results of `<cfdirectory>`.

Comment: Agreed. I'd say a fair percentage of the time if one is needing to do a QoQ then there's a good chance there's a better way to achieve the same ends at the DB level before it gets to the CFML server.

Comment: *achieve the same ends at the DB level* +1. What is the reason for using QoQ's here instead of a db query? If the reason is lack of familiarity with sql (as some of your threads suggest) you should re-evaluate your approach. It is likely someone could suggest a more efficient approach if you explain your ultimate goal and provide the relevant specs (table ddl, current sql, sample data, etcetera) (Tools like http://sqlfiddle.com are helpful for sharing your db schema and sample data.)

Comment: If I have data already pulled from cfc methods and I want to do a quick left outer join it would be very helpful to do so in a CF QoQ. I found http://instantbadger.blogspot.com/2006/07/faking-left-outer-join-in-query-of.html but I got errors when the getUnMatchedListElems() was not robust enough to ensure data type matching (Q timestamp was matched to varchar and kablooey). Yes I can (and will) do a new method, but it would be nice to have a way for that once-in-a-while situation where I already have the data and running a new query pulls redundant data :/

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that there is no left outer join in ColdFusion's query of queries. The method you have shown is a common solution. If you are using the the ColdBox MVC Platform, there is actually a plugin that does left outer joins for you.

http://wiki.coldbox.org/wiki/Plugins:QueryHelper.cfm#doLeftOuterJoin

Disclaimer: I am part of Team ColdBox.

Comment: got it, but there is still inner join, join, union correct?

Comment: Yes, of course.  And to be clear, just in case there is confusion a "query of query" (when dbtype="query") is not executed on your database server.  It's an in-memory operation performed by ColdFusion.  CF supports a subset of SQL operations against in-memory result sets as you have found out.  Query of queries can be very fast and handy for small data sets, but beware of potential performance drops using large queries (more than a few thousands rows)

Answer (score 1):

If you're desperate and want some code in the right direction check http://instantbadger.blogspot.com/2006/07/faking-left-outer-join-in-query-of.html with the caveat this solution does not ensure datatype congruity when adding the new cross-referenced columns for the union.